# How to define mode-specific keys in evil-mode?

Tags: key-bindings, evil

I want keybinding *X* to do one thing in `c-mode` and another thing in other modes.  I'm trying to figure out how to do this in `evil`, specifically `evil`'s `insert-state`.

I tried setting the keybinding in a mode hook:

```el
(add-hook 'c-mode-hook (lambda ()
                         (define-key evil-insert-state-map (kbd "RET")
                           'c-indent-new-comment-line)))
```

And left everything else defined in my init file as:

```el
(define-key evil-insert-state-map (kbd "RET") 'comment-indent-new-line)
```

But the problem is that the hook does not seem to override my default keybinding.  **How do I override a key binding in `evil` based on a mode?**

Answer (score 3):

The standard way to set mode-specific keybindings in `evil` is to use:

```el
;; default
(define-key evil-insert-state-map (kbd "RET") 'comment-indent-new-line)
;; for other mode
(evil-define-key 'insert 'c-mode-map (kbd "RET") 'c-indent-new-comment-line)
```

N.b. `c-mode-map` is quoted.